# CSS Browser Specific issue in IE11

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a different behavior for table border in different browsers. In IE5 it rendered correct, but in IE 11, it is not.

In IE5 below behavior,

[image]

In IE 11, table border is coming on page, even when there is not items exists in table.

[image]

I tried below things to remove border,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with below code snippet,

> table {
>       border-spacing: 0px; }